# onTapGesture does not execute when tab is selected with swift UI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am simply trying to use the `onTapGesture` function to change the value of the variable `selectedTab` when a tab is picked by the user. This `onTapGesture` function seems to not work because my variable isn't changing value and when I add a print statement that doesn't even execute.

```
    @Binding var selectedTab: Bool
    @EnvironmentObject var authViewModel: AuthViewModel
    var body: some View {
        TabView(){
            NavigationView(){
                FeedView()
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "h.circle")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.selectedTab = false
                    }
            }
```

Comment: What you want is `TabView(selection: $selectedTab) { ... }`

Comment: Hello thanks. I have tried that and its not working, I also get this error in my console "Gesture: System gesture gate timed out." any thoughts

Comment: What I suggested saves the value of the selected tab in the State var. You don't need an additional `onTapGesture` as TabView does that automatically. By setting the var in the code you can jump between tabs programmatically. Is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to save the value of selected tab in the var and then check the value of this var in another swift ui view. I used the example added below but I dont know how to call this var in another swift ui view

Comment: @ChrisR never mind got it, all I had to use is a binding. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can receive changing of a `tabBar` with `TabView(selection:)`, `.tag` and `.onReceive`. Also don't forget to `import Combine` at the top of your file.

Here's an example:

```
@State private var selectedTab = 1
var body: some View {
    TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Navigation view #1")
        }
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "h.circle")
            Text("Home")
        }.tag(1)
        
        NavigationView {
            Text("Navigation view #2")
        }
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "d.circle")
            Text("Home")
        }.tag(2)
    }
    .onReceive(Just(selectedTab)) { _ in
        print("Your text here")
    }
}
```

Comment: if I wanted to get the value of selected tab in another swift UI view file how would I do this?

Comment: nevermind got it, your amazing

Comment: @wfrgegeg you can read about passing the data between views here: https://www.createwithswift.com/tutorial-passing-data-between-views-in-swiftui-using-state-and-binding/ Also, if my answer helped you, please mark it as a solution

Comment: Hello maybe you can help with this Im struggling. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76792454/closing-keyboard-causes-matched-geometry-effect-to-execute-swift-ui