# mapView swift causes warning "Has mesh errors"

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mapkit

Hello I am creating a simple map with a circle overlay and every time I run it on the sim I get the warning below. Id appreciate any help to get ride of it. I tried adding the circle overlay using a method but the warning still did not go away. When I geocode a location for Europe I also get another code (second one below). I could not find anything on google about these two.

" Missing MeshRenderables for ground mesh layer for (2/2) of ground tiles. Tile debug info: (Key: 0.1.2.255 t:34 kt:0, Has mesh errors: 0, MeshInstance count: 2, PendingMaterial count: 2, Invisible MeshInstances count: 0 | Key: 1.1.2.255 t:34 kt:0, Has mesh errors: 0, MeshInstance count: 2, PendingMaterial count: 2, Invisible MeshInstances count: 0)"

No config pack found for key Europe Central Shields

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
   @State private var coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(45.5202471, -122.6741949)
   let city: String
   let state: String
   let country: String
   let is100: Bool

   func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
       let mapView = MKMapView()
       mapView.delegate = context.coordinator

       let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
       var address = "\(city), \(state), \(country)"
       if state.isEmpty {
           address = "\(city), \(country)"
       }
       geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address) { placemarks, error in
           if let placemark = placemarks?.first, let location = placemark.location {
               self.coordinate = location.coordinate
               mapView.setCenter(self.coordinate, animated: true)
               
               let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, latitudinalMeters: is100 ? 20000 : 10000, longitudinalMeters: is100 ? 20000 : 10000)
               mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

               let regionRadius = is100 ? 10000.0 : 3500.0
               let circle = MKCircle(center: coordinate, radius: regionRadius)
               mapView.addOverlay(circle)
           }
       }
       return mapView
   }

   func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {}

   func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
       Coordinator()
   }

   class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
       func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
           if let circle = overlay as? MKCircle {
               let circleRenderer = MKCircleRenderer(circle: circle)
               circleRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.black
               circleRenderer.fillColor = UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
               circleRenderer.lineWidth = 1.0
               return circleRenderer
           }
           return MKOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay)
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible the [MapKit framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/) is unable to find the necessary mesh data for the ground tiles in the specified region.

In your case, a likely reason for the error is that the region is too large: you are setting the region to a width and height of 20000 meters, which is a very large area. The MapKit framework may not have enough memory to load all of the mesh data for this region. (as illustrated in "[Advanced MapKit Tutorial: Custom MapKit Tiles / Loading the Pre-rendered Tiles](https://www.kodeco.com/9697133-advanced-mapkit-tutorial-custom-mapkit-tiles#toc-anchor-009)") by  [Adam Rush](https://twitter.com/adam9rush).

Try and reducing the size of the region. You can also try zooming in on the map so that the region is smaller.

I see also "`No config pack found for key Europe Central Shields`", which is also related to the mesh data for the ground tiles. The MapKit framework needs to download this data in order to render the ground tiles. However, the framework may not be able to find the data for the "Europe Central Shields" config pack.
You can try restarting your device. This should force the MapKit framework to download the latest data.